# Regex match every occurance and wildcard condition

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex that will match the following conditions:

Where every instance of the occurance 'eVar7=' contains the following 'unav'

This should be false:

;AA;;;;eVar7=nr_unav,;AA;;;;eVar7=br_unavail,;AA;;;;eVar7=sugg,;AA;;;;eVar7=sugg,;AA;;;;eVar7=sugg

and this should return true: 
;AA;;;;eVar7=nr_unav,;AA;;;;eVar7=br_unavail,;AA;;;;eVar7=nr_unav,;AA;;;;eVar7=nr_unav11,;AA;;;;eVar7=nr_unavasdfasdferwgf

Answer (score 2):

This regex does the opposite. If there is a match means that you don't want it:

```
eVar7=(?![^;]*?unav)
```

It uses a negative lookahead. Meaning that after the eVar7 match there should not be something with "unav" in the middle. If so, it matches.

This is just to put you on the right track however as there are a lot to consider with your examples. For example where exactly should this "unav" pattern exist. What characters are allowed between eVar7 and "unav" etc. Feel free to change the regex to suit your needs.

Comment: This does not always work though. For example, the string `eVar7=GARBAGE;;;eVar7=nr_unav` will *not* match your regex, which means it is supposedly OK. However, as you can see the first eVar7 is followed by GARBAGE. It does not match because it just skips over it, and finds the `unav` at the end. Technically the first eVar7 is of course followed by the `unav`, but the OP most likely meant "directly" followed, i.e., before another eVar7 is found.

Comment: +1 - so much cleverer than my naïve idea of counting the matches of "ever7=" and "unav" and seeing if they are equal. Edit: in the light of Daniël's comment, I couldn't remove my +1. I'm sure he could find fault with my idea too.

Comment: Regardless the question you can omit last `.*?` in regex, giving `eVar7=(?!.*?unav)`, and better to use `[^;]` instead of `.`, giving `eVar7=(?![^;]*unav)`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: Yes I know. Like I mentioned the OP has to change this to suite their needs. For example if a ; is a valid delimiter between the key, value pairs. Then the regex can easily be changed to accommodate that.

Comment: All good comments. Updated the pattern.

Comment: The adjusted regex now works properly on the counter-example I gave earlier, so +1 :)

Comment: Will this work in java?